# Awkward looking uses of Contract.ValueAtReturn()

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, code-contracts

I am designing a method that will add an element to an internal list. The structure of the class is something along the lines of:

```
class MyCustomerDatabase {
    private IList<Customer> _customers = new List<Customer>();

    public int NumberOfCustomers { get { return _customers; } }    

    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer) {
        _customers.Add(customer);
    }
}
```

Now, I was thinking of adding a `Contract.Ensures()` about the size of the _customers growing by 1 with this call. The problem is that I end up with some weird looking code:

```
public void AddCustomer(Customer customer) {
    int numberOfCustomersAtReturn;
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn<int>(out numberOfCustomersAtReturn) == 
Contract.OldValue<int>(NumberOfCustomers) + 1);


    _customers.Add(customer);
    numberOfCustomersAtReturn = NumberOfCustomers;
}
```

The main problem is that properties are in fact methods, so you can't just reference them direcly when using `Contract.ValueAtReturn()` as its only parameter accepts variables as `out`.
The situation gets even odder if I want to achieve the same but this time with a method that should return a value:

```
public int MyReturningMethod() {
    ...
   return abc(); //abc will add by one the number of customers in list
}
//gets converted to
public int MyReturningMethod() {
    int numberOfCustomersAtReturn;
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn<int>(out numberOfCustomersAtReturn) == Contract.OldValue<int>(NumberOfCustomers) + 1);

    int returnValue = abc();
    numberOfCustomersAtReturn = NumberOfCustomers;
    return returnValue;
}
```

This seems pretty clumsy :(

Code Contracts should aim to get things clearer and this seems right the opposite. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're overcomplicating things for no reason. [`ValueAtReturn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412864.aspx) is used to talk about `out` parameters to a method, and nothing else — and you don't have any `out` parameters!

What you're looking for is [`OldValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412857.aspx).

Assuming that this line:

```
public int NumberOfCustomers { get { return _customers; } }
```

is meant to be:

```
public int NumberOfCustomers { get { return _customers.Count; } }
```

All you have to do is:

```
class MyCustomerDatabase
{
    private readonly IList<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

    public int NumberOfCustomers { get { return customers.Count; } }

    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        Contract.Ensures(NumberOfCustomers ==
                         Contract.OldValue(NumberOfCustomers) + 1);

        customers.Add(customer);
    }
}
```

The static checker can prove this just fine, thanks to the postconditions in `IList<T>` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing everything right.

Altough I have the feeling you are taking Contracts to the extreme by describing the exact output implications of calling that method. Imho the basic idea of Contracts was more to ensure ***basic*** guarantees, like being positive, returning a value at all and so on.

Comment: Hmm, that may be, indeed, true.

Comment: I think the fact that adding an item to a list makes it 1 item longer *is*, in fact, a basic guarantee ;)